# The ezstream service quits unexpectedly

Tags: streaming, systemd, daemon, exit, icecast

I have Icecast started at boot, running in the background, thus:

```
# systemctl status icecast2
● icecast2.service - LSB: Icecast2 streaming media server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/icecast2; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-02-27 05:26:53 CET; 3 weeks 5 days ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 623 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/icecast2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31649 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/icecast2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 10.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/icecast2.service
           └─684 /usr/bin/icecast2 -b -c /etc/icecast2/icecast.xml

Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

I also have ezstream which starts at boot but keeps quitting after several days, thus:

```
# systemctl status ezstream
● ezstream.service - source client for Icecast with external de-/encoder support
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ezstream.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2022-03-18 13:24:01 CET; 1 weeks 0 days ago
  Process: 21047 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ezstream -c ezstream_mp3.xml (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21047 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

The file `/lib/systemd/system/ezstream.service` contains:

```
[Unit]
Description=source client for Icecast with external de-/encoder support
Requires=icecast2.service
After=icecast2.service

[Service]
User=archiwum
WorkingDirectory=/home/archiwum/autopilot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ezstream -c ezstream_mp3.xml
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=icecast2.service
```

And `ezstream_mp3.xml` has the element setting the playlist to be auto-repeated: `<stream_once>0</stream_once>`.
The system is Debian 10 (`4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

Why does ezstream quit, then? And how to prevent it?
(For the time being, I'm probably going to issue the command `systemctl status ezstream` every minute as a workaround.)

Comment: Could it be that it cannot access the playlist file? It's sometimes regenerated by another process. But then the exit code of ezstream should be different from what it is (`0`, indicating success), right?

Comment: As a workaround, I've gone for replacing `Restart=on-failure` and `RestartSec=5` with just `Restart=always`.

Comment: have you checked the journal for messages related to ezstream?